# Does the cost vary based on the number of fields in a document in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question while using Firebase Firestore.

Getting a snapshot of Document A, which contains 10 fields, using Get().
Getting a snapshot of Document B, which contains 500 fields, using Get().
Do both approaches incur the same cost since they only involve a single Get() call? Or does the approach with more fields to retrieve result in higher costs, even though Get() is called only once?

Which one incurs more cost: getting a document with one NUMBER field using Get() 10 times, or getting a document with 10 NUMBER fields using Get() once? I'm curious about that.

Comment: Answer below. But this is now the third question in a row about Firestore pricing, and I'm pretty sure all of these have been covered before. I recommend reading other [questions about Firestore pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+pricing)  before asking further questions about the topic.

Comment: Best Practice is to search SO for similar questions before posting a question, keeping in mind that questions about pricing may be answered on the product developers website, as in this case, or should be directed to the product developer. Please stick with coding specific questions and as always, include your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown on both the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) and the [Firestore pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing), when you use Firestore you are charged for:

- Stored data
- Document writes
- Document reads
- Document deletes
- Network egress, so that is bandwidth used when you read data from the database

Reading a single document through `get()` leads to a single document read charge, and a bandwidth charge for the size of the document and overhead. A larger documents will lead to a larger bandwidth charge, but it will still only count as one document read.